# Why every tweet is being deleted

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

So I'm using React and I made a little code that has a textbox with a submit button, and when something is typed in and submitted, it creates a tweet with the text I typed in and some pre-made elements as you see here:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvfSf.png
The random letters with the Like and Delete buttons is what I submitted each time.

What I'm confused is why every single tweet gets deleted when I use this code:

```
const deleteTweet = () =>{
    setTweets(tweets.filter(tweet => tweet !== tweet))
}
```

But when I use this code, only the one specific tweet I clicked Delete on, gets removed:

```
const deleteTweet = () =>{
    setTweets(tweets.filter(t => t !== tweet))
}
```

The 'tweet' after the !== is a prop I'm passing down.

Comment: In `tweet !== tweet` both `tweet` are *the exact same variable*. There is no value that isn't equal to itself (except `NaN`), so `tweet !== tweet` is always `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a conflict between tweet used as parameter on map and tweet used as props, Javascript's scoping take the latest variable which is the map's tweet.

So when you put tweet on map function it overrides the props tweet.

You may take a look at closures : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures